# PyInstaller - include subprocess.Popen call with third party scripts in single file compilation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

[PyInstaller/Py2exe - include os.system call with third party scripts in single file compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603480/pyinstaller-py2exe-include-os-system-call-with-third-party-scripts-in-single-f)

Similar question was asked but I was not able to run using the above method. GUI was launch using the exe ( created using PyInstaller - bundle to folder) file and when I tried to run the script through GUI, it simply didn't launch

**Edit
PyQt code script_A

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    #code.....
    self.run_script = QPushButton("Run script_A", self)
    self.run_script.clicked.connect(self.script_call)


def script_call(self):
    subprocess.call("python script_B.py")
```

script_B

```
print("some value")
#
```

Script_A is converted to exe using pyinstaller (bundle to a folder). When I run the GUI using the exe file, I am not able to call the script_B.py with either subprocess.call or os.system

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the full path ("C:/path/to/your/file") or short ("file")?

Comment: I have use "file" and "parentfolder/file" but it didn't work. And I have not tried the full path. For example I have three scripts A, B, and C. Script A is the GUI code and scripts B and C will be run with os.system or subprocess.popen call and the path is simply the script B or C. Or it can be "parentfolder/script"